# JavaScript Help needed with pop up window and stop counter

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would love some help with this project. I am creating a small project with Javascript, I am still new with HTML,CSS, and JavaScript. What I would like to do with my program, is that the counter will stop after 1 minute has passed and a pop up window appears that no more clicks are accepted. Below is my code, any help will be appreciated!!

```
var count = 0;
var countblack = 0;
var countred = 0;
var countButton = document.getElementById("black");
var countButtonC = document.getElementById("red");
var displayCount = document.getElementById("displayCount");

black.onclick = function() {
  count++;
  countblack++;
  displayCount.innerHTML = count;
  displayCountblack.innerHTML = countblack;
}

red.onclick = function() {
  count++;
  countred++;
  displayCount.innerHTML = count;
  displayCountred.innerHTML = countred;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wr1ua0db/544/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` to count 60seconds and then disable the buttons. Below is the solution

```js
var allowClick = true;
var count = 0;
var countblack = 0;
var countred = 0;
var black = document.getElementById("black");
var red = document.getElementById("red");
var displayCount = document.getElementById("displayCount");
var displayBlackCount = document.getElementById("displayBlackCount");
var displayRedCount = document.getElementById("displayRedCount");

black.onclick = function() {
  if (!allowClick) return;

  count++;
  countblack++;
  displayCount.innerHTML = count;
  displayBlackCount.innerHTML = countblack;
}

red.onclick = function() {
  if (!allowClick) return;

  count++;
  countred++;
  displayCount.innerHTML = count;
  displayRedCount.innerHTML = countred;
}

startTime(60); // time in seconds

function startTime(time) {
  var timer = setTimeout(function() {
    black.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    red.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    allowClick = false;
    clearTimeout(timer)
  }, 1000 * time)
}
```

```html
<button id="black">Count Black</button>
<button id="red">Count Red</button>

<div>Display Count: <span id="displayCount">0</span></div>
<div>Black Count: <span id="displayBlackCount">0</span></div>
<div>Red Count: <span id="displayRedCount">0</span></div>
```